# How do these actions resolve and bubble in this Ember.js app?

Tags: ember.js

Here is my basic app in Ember.js:

This is my app/router.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('todos', { path: '/'}, function() {
    this.route('complete');
    this.route('incomplete');
  });
});

export default Router;
```

So when I hit the root path or '/', my application.hbs loads first, then my app/templates/todos.hbs, then my app/templates/todos/index.hbs right? The app/templates/todos/index.hbs gets loaded inside the outlet of the todos.hbs right?

This is my app/templates/todos.hbs:

```
<p>
  this is the app/templates/todos.hbs.
</p>
{{todo-input action="createTodo"}}
{{#todo-list todos=model}}
    {{outlet}}
{{/todo-list}}
```

So my todo-input component has an action called 'createTodo'. When does this get called?

This is my todo-input component handlebars template:

```
<p>
  this is the todo-input.hbs component. It gets called inside todos.hbs
</p>
{{input type="text" id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?"
    value=newTitle enter="submitTodo"}}
```

**Questions**:

1. When I hit enter in the input field, it calls submitTodo right? Where does it look first? Does it look in the component's js file which is app/components/todo-input.js right? This is that code:

   ```
   import Ember from 'ember';

   export default Ember.Component.extend({
     actions: {
       submitTodo(newTitle) {
         if (newTitle) {
           this.sendAction('action', newTitle);
         }
             this.set('newTitle','');
       }
     }
   });
   ```
2. What argument gets passed to the submitTodo method?
3. What is this line:

   ```
   this.sendAction('action', newTitle);
   ```
4. Where should I define this 'createTodo' action? Should it be put in the routes/todos.js ?

   import Ember from 'ember';

   export default Ember.Route.extend({
       model() {
           return this.store.findAll('todo');
       },
       actions: {
           createTodo(newTitle) {
              this.store.createRecord('todo', {
                  title: newTitle,
                  complete: false
              }).save();
           }
       }
   });

I am mainly confused as to how the action in this line:

```
{{todo-input action="createTodo"}}
```

relates to the enter attribute in the todo-input component template:

```
{{input type="text" id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?"
    value=newTitle enter="submitTodo"}}
```

When does the action createTodo even get fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I hit enter in the input field, it calls submitTodo right?

Yes, because you've specified that this action should fire on enter event. [More info can be found here.](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/templates/input-helpers/#toc_actions)

> Where does it look first? Does it look in the component's js file
>   which is app/components/todo-input.js right?

Yes, it does look in component's javascript code for appropriate action.

> What argument gets passed to the submitTodo method?

Input value is passed to to `submitTodo` action as first and only argument.

> What is this line:

```
this.sendAction('action', newTitle);
```

It fires an action passed as parameter (in this case `createTodo`) to component with `newTitle` as argument.

> Where should I define this 'createTodo' action? Should it be put in
>   the routes/todos.js ?

Controller would be better place for your action, so you should put `createTodo` action in `controllers/todos.js`.

> When does the action createTodo even get fired?

Check this out:

1. User presses enter when he has input focused
2. Input helper fires action attached to enter event - which is `submitTodo`
3. `submitTodo` gets called because it's located in component's actions set
4. `submitTodo` calls action passed to `todo-input` component with `this.sendAction()` - this action is `createTodo`